# How to animate two arrows to go back and forth

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text with arrows around , show up using `contrastShow` function like this:

```js
function contrastShow(text) {
    const contrast = document.getElementById("contrast");
  contrast.innerHTML = `<span class="right-arrow arrow">&#8249;</span>${text}<span class="left-arrow arrow">&#8250;</span>`;
  contrast.classList.add("contrastShow");
  contrast.classList.remove("contrastHide");
}


contrastShow("Text with animated arrows around");

setTimeout(() => {

    // adding arrow animation
    const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
  arrows.forEach(arrow => {
    arrow.classList.add("loop");
  });

}, 2500);
```

```css
.contrast-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.vertical-center-contrast {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.arrow {
  color: #e9e1f2;
}

.left-arrow {
  padding-right: 7vw;
}

.right-arrow {
  padding-left: 7vw;
}

.loop {
    -webkit-animation: backandforth 2s ease 0s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation: backandforth 2s ease 0s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes backandforth {0%{left:0;} 50%{left:58%;} 100%{left:0;}}

@keyframes backandforth {0%{left:0;} 50%{left:100%;} 100%{left:0;}}


.contrast {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Vazir";
    direction: rtl;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgb(248, 247, 250);
    opacity: 0;  
    margin: 0 auto;
   
}

#original {
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.contrastShow {
    animation: contrastAnimeShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

.contrastHide {
    animation: contrastAnimeHide 0.3s ease-in-out;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes contrastAnimeShow {
  0%    { opacity: 0; top: 4vh }
  100%  { opacity: 1; top: 1.2vh }
}

@-webkit-keyframes contrastAnimeHide {
  0%    { opacity: 1; top: 1.2vh }
  100%  { opacity: 0; top:  4vh }
}
```

```html
<div class ="vertical-center-contrast contrast-container">
        <p id="contrast" class="contrast"></p>
    </div>
```

I want arrows with a simple animation of back and forth to left and right ... (first they should go toward the text and then both should get away from the text )

And here is what I want:

[image]

And then:

[image]

I have tried many things with no luck...please help...

Comment: How do you want the animation to look (flipping or rotating)? What have you tried that didn't work? Have you looked into [`transform: rotate(90deg);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate())